# MongoDB 2.6.10 segfaults while reindexing in background on SmartOS

Tags: mongodb, segmentation-fault, smartos

Caught a segfault in 2.6.10 rebuilding indexes in the background, would appreciate any pointers on how to narrow down the culprits (or report this as a bug with MongoDB):

```
2015-06-25T16:07:04+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [conn280829] end connection RFC1918_ADDR:48187 (624 connections now open)#012
2015-06-25T16:07:04+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] connection accepted from RFC1918_ADDR:43724 #280833 (625 connections now open)#012
2015-06-25T16:07:04+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [conn280833]  authenticate db: local { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "__system", key: "xxx" }#012
2015-06-25T16:07:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [conn265743] CMD: dropIndexes APP.APPs#012
2015-06-25T16:07:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [conn265743] halting index build: { topLikes: 1 }#012
2015-06-25T16:07:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.crit] [conn265743] Invalid access at address: 0x38#012
2015-06-25T16:07:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[60550]: [ID 702911 local7.crit] [conn265743] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation Fault).#012Backtrace:0x1325fe8 0x1325952 0x1325a00 0xfffffd7fff197256 0xfffffd7fff18a00b 0xde2dbc 0xf6007d 0xe16e47 0xe175ee 0xe8eb34 0xe8fa4b 0xe905de 0x106e5c1 0xf6c0dd 0xd00357 0x12ed0fa 0xfffffd7f28394816 0xfffffd7fff196e7a 0xfffffd7fff197190 #012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x28 [0x1325fe8]#012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_110abruptQuitEi+0x92 [0x1325952]#012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_124abruptQuitWithAddrSignalEiP7siginfoPv+0x80 [0x1325a00]#012 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'__sighndlr+0x6 [0xfffffd7fff197256]#012 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'call_user_handler+0x1db [0xfffffd7fff18a00b]#012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog23killMatchingIndexBuildsERKNS0_17IndexKillCriteriaE+0x1cc [0xde2dbc]#012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12IndexBuilder23killMatchingIndexBuildsEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_12IndexCatalog17IndexKillCriteriaE+0x1d [0xf6007d]#012 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20213 port=27018 dbpath=/var/mongodb 64-bit host=rs0db1.HOST#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] build info: SunOS pkgsrc-pbulk-2014Q4-2.local 5.11 joyent_20141030T081701Z i86pc BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_57#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] allocator: system#012
2015-06-25T17:15:13+00:00 rs0db1 mongod.27018[20213]: [ID 702911 local7.info] [initandlisten] options: { config: "/opt/local/etc/mongod.conf", cpu: true, net: { http: { enabled: false }, port: 27018 }, operationProfiling: { mode: "slowOp" }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" }, security: { authorization: "enabled", keyFile: "/opt/local/etc/mongo.replica-key" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/mongodb", directoryPerDB: true }, systemLog: { destination: "syslog", syslogFacility: "local7" } }#012
```

Comment: Do you have a core dump?

Comment: In the global zone, check /zones/:uuid/cores, where :uuid is the UUID of the zone.